# Automatic or Silent update using sparkle framework for mac

Tags: macos, sparkle

I am trying to do Auto or Silent update of my mac app using Sparkle framework and I added the key SUEnableAutomaticChecks to YES in my info.plist. I write the code in AppController like below :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    //Sparkle auto update
    SUUpdater *sparkleUpdater = [SUUpdater sharedUpdater];
    [sparkleUpdater checkForUpdates:self];
    sparkleUpdater.delegate = [[NRMUpdateDelegate alloc] init];
    [sparkleUpdater setAutomaticallyChecksForUpdates:YES];
    [sparkleUpdater setAutomaticallyDownloadsUpdates:YES];
    [sparkleUpdater checkForUpdatesInBackground];
}
```

Still I am getting the updater window to update install the new version. I want to do all this in background.

Can anyone suggest me how can do this....

Answer (score -1):

As per the docs,

`[sparkleUpdater checkForUpdates:self];`

```
/*!
    Explicitly checks for updates and displays a progress dialog while doing so.

    This method is meant for a main menu item.
    Connect any menu item to this action in Interface Builder,
    and Sparkle will check for updates and report back its findings verbosely
    when it is invoked.
 */
```